# Find the position of a number in a range

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to find a position of a number in a custom range?

for example, I have a list of numbers from -10.0 to 5.0 with 1 decimal precision.
the total numbers in the range are 151 (inclusive of start and end values). -10.0 is at position 1 and 5.0 is at position 151. I am trying to find a query which can give me the position for 2.5 (i.e. position 126) in this range.

Table Structure:

id  | from  | to

1   | -10.0 | 5.0

2   | 658.5 | 835.0

3   | 32.5  | 65.3

4   | -32.5 | 65.0

The increment is default 0.1

Comment: Sure this is possible and likely not all that difficult. However, it is not at all clear what your table looks like or data. You need to provide those details so others can help. This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You have a a list of numbers where?  A table has no natural order.

Comment: and it can only be done if you have a sorting on your table

Comment: Is this list of numbers stored as one number per record, or do you instead have a list of numbers in a single record?

Comment: I have two fields in a table which specify the range (start_from and end_to)
value in start_from = -10.0
value in end_to = 5.0
I want to enter a number within this range and return the position of the number.

Comment: Show us the table and sample data. Guessing is not a good approach to this type of thing.

Comment: @r228302 Put that important information IN the question.   You have a start and end.  You do not have a list of numbers.

Comment: Besides start and end, you'd also need an increment. 1?   0.1?   0.01?

Comment: This is making less sense.  Fix the question.  VTC

Comment: the increment is default 0.1

Comment: If you would take 2-3 minutes and post the table definition and a couple rows of sample data you would already have an answer.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to use ROW_NUMBER() ordering by the numbers, and then select the row where the number equals the one you're interested in, and the row number will be the position. I can't give you an actual example because there's not enough detail in the question for me to write actual SQL to show you.

Comment: @pmbAustin I have updated the question. please let me know if the information is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another stab at stitching together the problem set.

At the heart of things, it's just a math problem:

```
--  Proof of concept
DECLARE
  @First      decimal(9,2)
 ,@Last       decimal(9,2)
 ,@Increment  decimal(9,2)
 ,@NewValue   decimal(9,2)
 ,@Position   int

SET @First     = -10.0
SET @Last      = 5.0
SET @Increment = .1
SET @NewValue  = 5.0

SET @Position = (@NewValue - @First) / @Increment + 1

PRINT @Position
GO
```

Next, assuming a table with First and Last values, the following would generate a "Position" value for each row in the table:

```
DECLARE @Test as TABLE
 (
   Id     int           not null  identity(1,1)
  ,First  decimal(9,2)  not null
  ,Last   decimal(9,2)  not null
 )

INSERT @Test (First, Last) values
  (-10.0, 5.0)
 ,(685.5, 835.0)
 ,(32.5, 65.3)
 ,(-32.5, 65)


DECLARE
  @TargetValue  decimal(9,2)
 ,@Increment    decimal(9,2)

SET @TargetValue = 0
SET @Increment = .1

SELECT
   Id
  ,First
  ,Last
  ,case
     when @TargetValue < First then null
     when @TargetValue > Last then null
     else cast((@TargetValue - First) / @Increment + 1 as int)
   end  Position
 from @Test
```

I'm hoping a modification to one or the other of these should help with the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you an idea of the calculation:

```
DECLARE @rangestart decimal(18,1) = -10.0;
DECLARE @rangeend decimal(18,1) = 5.0;
DECLARE @count int = @rangeend * 10 - @rangestart * 10 +1
DECLARE @search decimal(18,1) = 2.5;

SELECT @count - (@search * 10) AS position
```

So your query would look like this:

```
SELECT ((end_to * 10 - start_from * 10 + 1) - (2.5 * 10)) AS position FROM yourTable
```